# Keeping 100% Pageview height

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, flexbox, antd

I'm trying to keep my page to a single fixed view (100% height & width) and wrap any long content using react-custom-scrollbar found within Layout `<content>`.

Ideally I would like to only have a scrollbar within `<content></content>` to display my content. The issue may be because I have not defined any layout container sizing to support 100vh view (responsive)

Resources:
[Tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs/)
[Custom scrollbar](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars)

How can I achieve the single pageview assuming it's through css?

I am still pretty new with react-custom-scrollbar, How can I reset scroll position to the top when TabPane is loaded/clicked?

[image: Edit confident-lederberg-dw0to]

Page view
https://dw0to.csb.app/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set outermost div's `overflow` property to `hidden`. Then define a wrapper for your `<content>` component, and set its `overflow` property to `auto`.

I am not familiar with *antd*, but this is how it is done with CSS.

In this example, `App` encapsulates all elements, so that's why I set its `overflow` property to `hidden`.

JSX:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">

        //Your components

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I applied this in my App.js but still getting the same result when I set Scrollbars to 100vh. Are you able to look at my sandbox and see what's causing this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lederberg-dw0to?fontsize=14 Please see updated sandbox. It looks like it does not reach the bottom of the tab. As Tab 1 should contain END OF THE PARAGRAPH at the end.

Comment: @Mask-dCodex It is probably related with margins and/or paddings. Or height of the container which encapsulates the paragraphs. Better ask another question. It is not directly related with this question.

Comment: Thanks I will contain to look.